# awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `-eq' for reading (No such file or directory)

Tags: bash, awk

Im quite new to bash scripting and I tried checking through the previous examples of this error but I still dont undertand why this isnt working

Here is the snippit of code throwing up the error:

```
#!/bin/bash

function group_check(){
    if [[getent group | awk -F":" '{print$1}' -eq $1 ]] ; then
            echo "The user exists!"
    else
            echo "The user doesn't exist!"
    fi
}

group_check tim
group_check tam
```

Hopefully someone cant point out where im going wrong or perhaps even suggest a better way of doing this, but I would quite like to understand where im going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: The argument you have passed to awk is `-eq`, you need to put the command inside a subshell using `$()`. Also i don't know how it got that far as you also need to leave a space after the `[[`

Comment: there are easier ways of checking whether argument $1 in group.

Comment: Thanks folks you have all been quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare output of a command to a number, you have to enclose the command into `$(...)` to capture its output:

```
if [[ $( getent group | awk -F":" '{print$1}' ) -eq $1 ]] ; then
```

Note that the space after `[[` isn't optional.

Also note that `-eq` compares numbers, you should use `==` for string comparison.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Yeah I have to hit the books again by the looks of it. I'm confusing a number of things here, however this makes sense. Thanks again.